# Calling a Variable in a Concat statement on Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am calling the following expression purely in a variable activity as I am stepping through the logic to understand where this problem is coming from:

@concat('{d'',variables('QODBC Past Date'),''}')

I keep on getting the following error:

> Invalid
>   Position 25 Syntax error: Missing comma between arguments

I am clearly missing something, but when I remove either the variable expression inside the concat or the two strings, it works. Anyone know what I've gotten wrong here?

The desired output is 
{d'2020-04-08'}

This is a dynamic content that I am going to place in a SQL query for date filter context.

That variable is the date input that is created further up in the pipeline.

Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried...
@concat('{d'',activity('Set variable2').output.value,''}')

It still returns the same problem about the missing commas between arguments.

Comment: Since ' is the string delimiter you need to delimit it if you want it in the output. I am guessing that you can delimit it by doubling it up so try this: @concat('{d''',variables('QODBC Past Date'),'''}')  Notice 3 ' in a row in two places - one for the end of string and two to become one in the output.

Comment: Yup, I hadn't had a chance to post, but yes. This was the answer in the end. Thank you!

Comment: Created answer if you will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ' is the string delimiter you need to delimit it if you want it in the output. You can delimit it by doubling it up so try this:

```
@concat('{d''',variables('QODBC Past Date'),'''}')
```

Notice 3 ' in a row in two places - one for the end of string and two to become one in the output.

Comment: You can "escape" the single quote by doubling it.  Delimit has a different meaning.